# Sleep between characters using SendKeys

Tags: vbscript, sleep

I am trying to get a "ghost typing" kind of look in something I am doing. I am having to sleep between characters to get the effect. The way I'm doing it is taking a lot of lines of code:

```
set wshell = wscript.CreateObject("wScript.Shell")
wshell.sendkeys "1"
wscript.sleep 100
wshell.sendkeys "2"
wscript.sleep 100
wshell.sendkeys "3"
wscript.sleep 100
wshell.sendkeys "4"
wscript.sleep 100
```

Is there an easier way to do this instead of having to do this for each character?

Answer (score 1):

You could have your keys in an array and then just pass it to a subroutine to do the typing:

```
Set wshell = CreateObject("wScript.Shell")

GhostType Array("1", "2", "3", "4"), 100            ' 100ms delay  
GhostType Array("5", "{Tab}", "6", "{Enter}"), 200  ' Longer delay for these keys

Sub GhostType(arrKeys, intDelay)

    For Each k In arrKeys
        wshell.SendKeys k
        wshell.Sleep intDelay
    Next

End Sub
```

If you want to type just strings of characters without any control keys (tab, enter, alt, control, etc), you could write a subroutine that accepts a string and then sends each character individually, with a pause in between:

```
Set wshell = CreateObject("wScript.Shell")

GhostType "Type this sentence slowly...", 100
GhostType "and this one even slower.", 200

Sub GhostType(strText, intDelay)

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        wshell.SendKeys Mid(strText, i, 1)
        wshell.Sleep intDelay
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well I want it to look like it's typing. Like have it type out a sentence or 2. Like typing strings but sleep between each character

Comment: This should do the same thing your original script was doing -- pausing in between each keypress. I've added a second example if you have long sentences you want to use this for.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try that later and let you know if that works for what I need!